# Need help deciding on statistical test to use

Tags: hypothesis-testing, agreement-statistics

Suppose two individuals each categorize a large dataset into one of 12 categories, so we have the proportions of the dataset in each of the 12 categories that each individual calculated. What statistical test should I use to prove that there is no significant difference between the two individuals' measurements? I was told to use kolmogorov-smirnov test but that test doesn't feel right to me for this situation.

Comment: Do you really mean just 2 individuals? Inferential statistics make inferences about population parameters based on a sample from that population. How do you see your question fitting into that framework?

Comment: Permutation test should work.

Comment: Yes, two individuals or we can also say software that each does the categorizing, I want a test that will let me say that I am confident that they have no significant difference in measurements.